# Mounting existing VHDX on Win10 throws "You need to format disk" message

Tags: windows-10, vhdx

Need help trying to mount a VHDX used for storing files & projects (*it's not a VM*).

I'm moving a VHDX from my old Win10 laptop to the new one. When attaching the copied VHDX via Disk Management on the new laptop I'm prompted with, "*You need to format the disk in drive X before you can use it.*"

**Reproduce:**

1. Copy VHDX from old Win10 laptop to new Win10 (both NTFS)
2. DiskMgmt.msc
3. Action > Attach VHD
4. Select my VHDX file
5. Recieve error message above, followed by, "*The volume does not contain a recognized file system.*"

Note: Both machines have McAfee drive encryption installed on them

I did a SHA256 on both files & it's the same hash. Searched Google and Microsoft for hours and didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it help in your particular case, but, would suggest trying partition recovery with this tool: http://www.ntfs.com/recovery-toolkit.htm